# ¿Existe un proceso contrario a la función pd.get_dummies() en Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Estoy trabajando con un `CSV`, que contiene los siguientes datos (entre otros), que como se puede apreciar antes de exportar el `CSV` como tal, hicieron hicieron un `pd.get_dummies(data_csv)` separando la información de una columna por categorías, ahora mi deber es juntar toda la información relacionadas con el tipo de suelo, es decir, las columnas llamadas `Soil_Type[X]` que va desde el `Soil_Type1` a `Soil_Type40` y cambiar el nombre por el que corresponde:

```
      Soil_Type1          Soil_Type2          Soil_Type3          Soil_Type4
0          1                   0                   0                   0
1          0                   0                   1                   0
2          0                   1                   0                   0
3          0                   0                   0                   1
4          1                   0                   0                   0
```

Puse las primeras 4 columnas para que se pudiera apreciar más o menos el formato que tiene la data

Tengo otro `DataFrame` donde tengo la data que corresponde al nombre del tipo:

```
    Soil_Type
1 | Cathedral family - Rock outcrop complex, extre... //aquí sería Soil_Type1
2 | Vanet - Ratake families complex, very stony.
3 | Haploborolis - Rock outcrop complex, rubbly.
4 | Ratake family - Rock outcrop complex, rubbly.
```

Entonces la data final se tendría que ver así, en una sola columna dependiendo del número:

```
    Soil_Type
0 | Cathedral family - Rock outcrop complex, extre...
1 | Haploborolis - Rock outcrop complex, rubbly.
2 | Vanet - Ratake families complex, very stony.
3 | Ratake family - Rock outcrop complex, rubbly.
4 | Cathedral family - Rock outcrop complex, extre...
```

Para lograr lo anterior hice el siguiente código:

```py
new  = None #Creé esta variable para guardar la info que pasa por el for
list_st = [] # una lista para almacenar la información en forma de diccionarios
# traigo columnas que lleven Soil_Type en el nombre al comienzo
for col in forest.filter(regex = '^Soil_Type'): 
  number = col[9:] # así solo el número que acompaña a Soil_Type, quitando las letras
  # así saco la fila donde el Soil_Type de turno, tenga un 1 
  new = forest.loc[forest[col]==1] 
  for index in new.Id.to_list(): #
    list_st.append( # añado a la lista
        {
        'id': index, # añado el id de la fila que saqué anteriormente
        'st': int(number) # el número que sacamos al principio
        }
    )

#Lo transforma a DF
st = pd.DataFrame(list_st)
```

Haciendo lo anterior la variable `st` almacena los datos correctamente, como se puede apreciar a continuación:

```
   id   st
    0   1
    1   3
    2   2
    3   4
    4   1
```

Después de eso, hago un `merge()` de lo anterior con la data original, y otra vez vuelvo a hacer un `merge()` al `DataFrame`, donde están los nombres de los tipos de suelo, si bien todo se añade correctamente, es bastante tedioso. *Además soy totalmente nueva en pandas y me parece que lo que estoy haciendo es bastante repetitivo.* Por lo mismo, si es que existe una función como `pd.get_dummies()`

## **¿Existe alguna que haga totalmente lo contrario, como lo que hice anteriormente?**

Que deje tal que así:

```
    Soil
0   Type1
1   Type3
2   Type2
3   Type4
4   Type1
```

**Así solo tendría que sacar el número de la columna y hacer `merge()`**

Answer (score -1):

Es esto lo que buscas?

```
pd.Series(df.columns.str.replace(r"Soil_",""), name="Soil")
0    Type1
1    Type2
2    Type3
3    Type4
Name: Soil, dtype: object
```

Ahí está como Serie, aquí como DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(df.columns.str.replace(r"Soil_",""), name="Soil"))
     Soil
0   Type1
1   Type2
2   Type3
3   Type4
```